# Zoneminder on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, zoneminder

I am new to Kubernetes. I am trying to implement zoneminder on Kubernetes. I noticed from google I found quantumobject which is implementing zoneminder on docker, but the resources of implementing it on Kubernetes are really less. I tried implementing it on Kubernetes but somehow it doesn't show the video stream and by tracing the log I'm not able find any solution. Is anyone out there tried it ?

The tutorial I have referred to is https://github.com/QuantumObject/docker-zoneminder . It is a docker way to implement zoneminder on the container. So, i used the images and create my own yaml files which are
[mysql yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhPLJ.png)

this is the container for the mysql and after i create is i will pass the ip address to my zoneminder yaml file
[zm yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UyDR.png)

The zoneminder success to come up but when i add on ip cams, these are the errors
[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLr9d.png)

Answer (score 1):

I was just quickly researching this myself. Should run fine - it can even run multiple pods with shared storage per https://zoneminder.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installationguide/multiserver.html